# is there a way to truncate this horizontal alignment?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to align a ton columns to general and left, and I tried doing things like `with ws` and then `.columns(1,3,10,15).horizontalalignment = xlGeneral` but it seems to only be allowing me to do each column alignment as one row of code at a time.

How can I condense this:

```
.Columns(14).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
.Columns(15).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
.Columns(16).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
.Columns(18).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
.Columns(19).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
.Columns(17).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.Columns(20).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

to only two lines of code `xlGeneral` and `xlLeft` for the columns I specify?

Comment: Have you tried `.Columns("N:S").HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral`?

Comment: `Range("N:P,R:S").HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral` or if you have to refer to them as numbers, something like `Union(Range(Columns(14), Columns(16)), Range(Columns(18), Columns(19))).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral` Maybe?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks a bunch!